# List comprehension optimization

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I managed to convert 8 lines of code into just 2 lines.

The first list comprehension gets me the folder and the second gets me the files of specific filter:

```
hideTheseFolders=[".thumb",".mayaSwatches","RECYCLER","$AVG"]
fileFilters=["ma","jpg","png","mb",'iff','tga','tif']
newLst=[]
import os
locationTxt="E:\box\scripts"
[newLst.append(each) for each in os.listdir(locationTxt)  if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(locationTxt,each)) and each not in hideTheseFolders]
[newLst.append(os.path.basename(os.path.join(locationTxt,each))) for nfile in fileFilters for each in os.listdir(locationTxt) if each.endswith(nfile)]
```

Now in the above code the last two lines are looking inside same directory from `locationTxt`, which means there is probably a way that I can merge the last two lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you appending to a list inside a list comprehension?

Comment: I'd suggest that two lines is just fine. There's already plenty going on in each of them (neither fits on a standard line length anyway), and each does something distinct. Presumably you could just do `newLst.extend()` with the result of each comprehension, rather than appending to `newLst` within the comrehensions?

Comment: Why would you even want to merge this into two lines?

Comment: Also, do you realise that `os.path.basename(os.path.join(d, f))` is always equal to `os.path.basename(f)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List comprehensions are not a technique for optimisation. When the Python compiler sees a list comprehension, it breaks it down into a for loop. Look at bytecode 13 (`FOR_ITER`):

```
In [1]: from dis import dis

In [2]: code = "[i for i in xrange(100)]"

In [3]: dis(compile(code, '', 'single'))
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_NAME                0 (xrange)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (100)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                12 (to 28)
             16 STORE_NAME               1 (i)
             19 LOAD_NAME                1 (i)
             22 LIST_APPEND              2
             25 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   28 POP_TOP             
             29 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

The fact that a list comprehension is *the same* as a for loop can also be seen by timing it. In this case, the for loop actually worked out slightly (but insignificantly) faster:

```
In [4]: %timeit l = [i for i in xrange(100)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.6 us per loop

In [5]: %%timeit l = []; app = l.append  # optimise out the attribute lookup for a fairer test
   ...: for i in xrange(100):
   ...:     app(i)
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.9 us per loop  #  insignificant difference. Run it yourself and you might get it the other way around
```

You can therefore write any given list comprehension as a for loop with a minimal performance hit (in practice there is usually a small difference due to attribute lookup), and often a significant readability benefit. In particular, loops which have side effects should *not* be written as list comprehensions. Nor should you use list comprehensions that have more than about two `for` keywords, or which make a line longer than 70 characters or so. These aren't hard-and-fast rules, just heuristics for writing readable code.

Don't get me wrong, list comprehensions are very useful, and can often be clearer, simpler and more concise than an equivalent for-loop-and-append. But they are not to be abused in this way.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you're abusing list comprehensions to hide loops by appending inside them; you're actually throwing away the result of the list comprehension. Second, there's no need to cram as much as possible into a single line at the expense of readability.

If you want to use list comprehensions, which is actually a pretty good idea when building lists by looping and filtering, then consider this version:

```
ignore_dirs = set([".thumb",".mayaSwatches","RECYCLER","$AVG"])
extensions = ["ma", "jpg", "png", "mb", 'iff', 'tga', 'tif']
location = "E:\\box\\scripts"

filelist = [fname for fname in os.listdir(location)
                  if fname not in ignore_dirs
                  if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(location, fname))]
filelist += [os.path.basename(fname)
             for fname in os.listdir(location)
             if any(fname.endswith(ext) for ext in extensions)]
```

Note that there are still two comprehensions, because you seem to be building a list that logically consists of two kinds of items. There's no need to try and do that in a single expression, although you could have used two comprehensions with a `+` in between them instead of the `+=` statement.

(I took the liberty of renaming the variables to reflect what they represent.)

Answer (score 0):

The main suggestion is to get a decent Python book and read it well. Judging from your code you have no idea how list comprehensions work, still you managed to cram 8 readable lines of code into 2 overly long and incomprehensible ones.

You should write programs that are easy to read:

- newlines are your friends, use them
- spaces are your friends too
- lines should fit on the screen (<50 characters)
- put `imports` in the beginning of the file
- read a python book

Just in case you're wondering, here's what your code should look like:

```
import os

path = 'e:/box/scripts'

newLst = list()
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path) :
    # add folders
    newLst.extend( [dir for dir in dirs if dir not in hideTheseFolders] )

    # add files
    newLst.extend( [file for file in files if file.lower().endswith(fileFilters)] )

    break    # don't descend into subfolders

# convert to the full path or whatever you need here
newLst = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in newLst]
```

Comment: believe me I did not cram, but its upto you how you want to think.

Comment: the question that is still unanswered but accepted what is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to a code that is more readable and avoid list comprehension or will keep a backup reference to a readable if I have to do list comprehension.

So far my learning for doing list comprehension I would put that so that everyone can follow along.

The primary uses for comprehension are:

- grabbing the result of an iterator (possibly with a filter) into a permanent list: `files = [f for f in list_files() if f.endswth("mb")]`
- converting between iterable types: `example = "abcde"; letters = [x for x in example] # this is handy for data packed into strings!`
- simple list processing: `strings = [str(x) for x in list_of_numbers]`
- more complex list processing with lambdas for readability:
  `filter_func = lambda p, q: p > q
  larger_than_last = [val for val in list_of_numbers if filter_func(val, 5)]`

> Thank you everyone for your input and nailing.

An update: My research and troubleshooting has got me the exact answer.

```
filters = [[".thumb", ".mayaSwatches", "RECYCLER", "$AVG"], ["ma", "jpg", "png", "mb", 'iff', 'tga', 'tif']]
locationTxt = r"E:\box\scripts"
newLst = [each for each in os.listdir(locationTxt) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(locationTxt, each)) and each not in filters[0]] + [each for each in os.listdir(locationTxt) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(locationTxt, each)) and os.path.splitext(each)[-1][1:] in filters[1]]
```

however as I mentioned sticking to a readable code logic is the way to go!!!

Comment: You seem to have grasped it! Note that `letters = [x for x in example]` could also be rendered as `letters = list(x)`.

Comment: Also, your example with the `lambda` reads better if you put the comparison inside the list comprehension: `[val for val in list_of_numbers if val > 5]`. If your filter function is more complicated than this, you should probably use a `def` statement, and give it a better name than `filter_func`.